# Generics with class with two or more types (Interfaces) error

Tags: java, generics, java-7

this is my class:

```
public class MyTreeMap
< K extends CharSequence, V extends CharSequence & Map > {
}
```

And my Main:

```
{MyTreeMap< String, String > s = new MyTreeMap < >();}
```

What is the error?
Netbeans Give me this error:

type argument String is not within bounds of type-variable K
  where K is a type-variable:
    K extends CharSequence declared in class MyTreeMap

type argument String is not within bounds of type-variable V
  where V is a type-variable:
    V extends String,Map declared in class MyTreeMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part: `V extends CharSequence & Map` means your second type needs to extend both which [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) does not.  Could you be looking for a Map of CharSequences?

```
public class MyTreeMap< K extends CharSequence, V extends Map<K, CharSequence> > {}
```

Following up on your comment, you can't use generics to accept two different object with different types (how would it know what to return when you call get).  You could create a wrapper class called `ValidTreeType` that has a Map and String property and make a Map of these.

Comment: thanks for reply, i want this: for example: put(" ", " " ) or put (" " , new HashMap<>()); is this valid code?

Comment: So it can take a CharSequence OR a Map?  This is actually not possible (it violates what Generics are trying to do (how would it know what to return when you call .get())

Comment: but your implementation can take this: put (" " , " " )?

Comment: My brain is a little fried trying to figure out how to instantiate the class I wrote :P  But I think my update addresses the limitations of Generics

Comment: ok. thanks for the reply.. (good explication), i want to complicate mi life jeje